# Which photoshop is she using?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

https://youtu.be/edKic78kOag?t=21

any way to tell which photoshop she's using? this was published on aug25, 2016 my closest bet is CC but i'm not sure

Comment: It's impossible to tell from these clips.

Comment: But more importantly: Why would it matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a software question only, very very unlikely to help future readers in any way

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why it matters, but you can see the icon for the [Device Preview](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/devicepreview.html) panel, which was added in CC 2015...

[image]